# Importing Modules

Tags: python, import

I'm just trying to run a basic python script by importing the script to a second python module. But when I try to run it keep getting an error that says:

```
"exceptions.ImportError: No module name AUTO"
```

Here is my code on the second module:

```
import AUTO

def main():
    pass

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
    AUTO.printDate()
```

AUTO is another module that has one function `printDate()` which just prints today's date. It just keeps error-ing out.

Comment: where (on the file system) is the "AUTO" module you try to import? what its file name? what is the output of your `sys.path`?

Comment: AUTO is the name of another python script that I have made

Comment: then rename it AUTO.py, and make sure that the script you're calling it from is in the **same** directory, cf my answer.

Answer (score 2):

to import another module, it shall:

- be a file that ends with `.py`
- be in python import's path:

  - anywhere in your `sys.path` or
  - in current directory or
  - in any directory below your current directory that has a `__init__.py` (but then you have to import it using `import thatdirectory.mymodule`)

if you don't respect those rules, your file will not be seen by python's import system.

let's suppose the code you have in your question is `foo.py`, you want to have `foo.py` and `AUTO.py` together in the same directory, wherever they are.

Comment: The file does end in .py though, its saved as `AUTO.py`. So it must be a directory problem then? I just need to figure out a way to find out what directory to save it in...

Comment: I figured it out, for some reason it wasn't saved in the current directory, so I just had to change it, works perfect!